# Access data in subclass from superclass

Tags: matlab, oop, object, subclass, superclass

I have an object from my own class `object` that inherits from my own class `data` and my own class `graphic` in MATLAB. To represent the object `object`, it uses properties and methods from the `data`-superclass. Now I want to draw my object `object` with methods from the `graphic`-superclass, but the methods in this superclass don't know anything about its `object`-subclass.

Is there a way to give the required data, that is stored in the `object`-subclass, to the `graphic`-superclass without putting this information into a function argument like `object.draw(this_data_stuff)` with the method `draw`from the `graphic`-superclass and the data `this_data_stuff` from the `object`-subclass?

The only way I figured out is to store the subclass object `object` as property in the `graphic`-superclass, but it seems odd to store a subclass-object as property in a superclass-object, while the subclass inherits from the same superclass.

EDIT:

**data-class:**

```
classdef data < handle

  properties
    data_stuff
  end

  methods

    function obj = data
    end

    function obj = compute(obj)
      obj.data_stuff = ... % math
    end

  end
end
```

**graphic-class:**

```
classdef graphic < handle

  properties
  end

  methods

    function obj = graphic
    end

    function obj = draw(obj)
      plot(obj.data_stuff,t) % ERROR, property 'data_stuff' is unknown
    end

  end
end
```

**object-class:**

```
classdef object < data & graphic

  properties
  end

  methods

    function obj = object
    end

  end
end
```

**Test:**

```
object_A = object;  % creates object
object_A.compute;   % generates data_stuff
object_A.draw;      % draws data_stuff, Error here, because 'draw` needs access to the 'data_stuff'-property.
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I'm understanding the question. If your class inherits the graphics super then it already has the super's methods. Why do you need to instantiate the super separately?

Comment: Yes, it has its methods but not the required data from the `object`subclass, that is needed by the drawing-methods in the `graphic`-superclass.

Comment: Your `object` subclass has the super's methods and the `object`'s data.

Comment: But the `objects`'s data is needed in the methods that are implemented in the `graphic`-superclass.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're trying to make. I would recommend a [mcve] because your explanation of the problem is not clear.

Comment: Other than missing `t` in the properties of `data` and using `t` instead of `obj.t` in `graphic`, this functions as expected.

Comment: You just won't be able to instantiate `graphic` on it's own. As you have it written it works fine though if you only instantiate `object`